# Initial Token mint in Substrate Blockchain

Tags: pallet, token

I have downloaded the [substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) and started working on a new project. For my project, I want to implement a native token. I've decided to use pallet balances to implement this native token, but I'm confused about the token minting process in this pallet. Also, is there any initial token mint available in this pallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial mint map can be setup in the [`GenesisConfig`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/2b4b33d01f22b1f4037a404597357f398e21224f/substrate/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L495). You can configure the initial balances of any number of accounts in there.

Minting can be done only by `root` via [`force_set_balance`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/033d4e86cc7eff0066cd376b9375f815761d653c/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L699); this call forces the balance of an account to a specific amount.

Comment: It was useful however, Can You please elaborate "Minting Can be done only by root"?

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/033d4e86cc7eff0066cd376b9375f815761d653c/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L762) that the call is only available to root. This means that the chain either needs the `Sudo` pallet, or the call needs to go through a governance proposal and be voted on.